# File system snapshots moongodb for backup

Tags: mongodb, backup

I have some questions about Backup with Filesystem Snapshots.
I just wonder that only taking the snapshot is equal to backup? It's because snapshot is the pointer to the disk block in the mongo manner ( copy on write )
If the original disc is broken, it can't be restored.

So the question is that if we want to need to backup, is only the filesystem snapshot enough or we need to implement additionally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A filesystem snapshot itself is surely not enough to backup your data. When using a filesystem snapshot, this does not help you with corrupted disks, etc. So you need to move the data in the snapshot to somewhere else.

When you create a snapshot, the changes applied to the original data files will fill up the remaining space, in case of LVM snapshot even just the space explicitly allocated. So you need to over provision your disks by at least the amount the data you write within the time you need to process the backup and store it on a remote location.

> **Note** In the following description, most security considerations are set aside for the sake of brevity. You *must* apply the security measures appropriate for your data, for example using stunnel for the encryption of the data transfer when using the first approach.

## One approach

Here is what I tend to do to keep the need for over provisioning your disk size, CPU and RAM as low as possible while still being able to create snapshots and use them properly. Note that this is sort of a poor mans solution (when being really tight on budget) and you really should carefully think about wether this solution suits you.

I usually have a cheapo VM as a backup system, with some big, cheap, slow(ish) storage attached.  On that VM, I open a listening [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc), piping it's output through some sort of compressor. I use my own [snap](https://github.com/mwmahlberg/snap) for that, which is a crude implementation utilizing the [snappy compression algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_(software)). The reason is that snappy is optimized for speed rather than size, and that is what I am interested in here to reduce the time needed for getting the snapshot from the MongoDB server.

```
nc -l <internalIp> <somePort> | snap > /mnt/datastore/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%Z).tar.sz
```

Make sure you only listen to an internal IP or one you have limited access to via a firewall.

Next, I mount my snapshot (how to do that varies) on the MongoDB server I took the backup at. Then I jump to the directory I mounted said snapshot into (the one containing the data folder) and run `tar` over it, piping the output to another `netcat`, which sends the tarred data to the netcat listening on the backup server

```
tar -cv <directory> | nc <internalIpOfBackupServer> <listeningPort>
```

## Another approach

This is basically the same, though it utilizes ssh instead of `nc`:

```
tar -cv <directory> | ssh user@backupserver "snap > /mnt/datastore/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%T%Z).tar.sz"
```

We are trading speed for security here. This approach will take considerably longer and needs more resources on the machine you take the backup from.

## Some thoughts

You really want the snapshot be moved and archived on another server as fast as possible so that you can destroy the snapshot and return to normal operations. This way, you can reduce the necessary over provisioning of your resources to a bare minimum. Since RAM is a very precious resource on any MongoDB deployment, you want the compression to be done on a different machine.

If space is an issue on your backup machine, you can either use `gzip` or `bzip2` instead of `snap` right away (reducing the speed with which the backup is done), or you can do the following on the backup machine after the backup is finished:

```
snap -c -u yourBackup.tar.sz | bzip2 -v9 > yourBackup.tar.bz2
rm yourBackup.tar.sz
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I'm sorry that I'm little confused about this part " ...So you need to move the data in the snapshot to somewhere else ..".  As for as I understand, snapshot in LVM is just a pointer recording the difference from the previous one.  What I want to do here is just to attache some 2nd disk, and the put the backups there.

Comment: You are right. But what if the datacenter burns down? Or just the server with the backup? Backups belong to off site.

Comment: That's totally right, thanks again. I have one more question ( I'm new to LVM so it might be wrong ).  Moving the data in the snapshot is great idea to avoid disc corruption, but what about the original data ? Without original data, it's impossible to restore cause snapshot itself is just a pointers. So the question is where should I put the original data? Maybe I should have RAID or replication for that ?

Comment: The ***mounted*** snapshot is real data and is the exact state of the files as they have been when you took the snapshot. You tar/compress/send the mounted data. Then, you unmount and destroy the snapshot. As can be seen in http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

Comment: Thanks again, so you mean after taking some snapshot, I need to mount it to the original one and copy it to the separated storage, which is the backup, right? ( maybe I can use dd command )

Comment: @Toshi NOoooooooo. Mount it to `/mnt/snapshot` or somewhere else, back a file based backup store that away like described and you are good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I got it :)